# Webpart access denied error on WebPart page

Tags: 2010, web-part, permissions

I've added a Document Library webpart to a non-webpart page. The user has no access to the document library. When the user visits the page nothing is displayed. All as expected.
Then I add the same webpart to a new web part page and the same user sees an error 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource'
Is this error normal on a web part page ?

As a workaround I've created an 'Open' permission and added this to the library or I could use target audience.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to have both.If you do not want user to see access denied msg. and If you have unique permission to library and you want to have it on web part page. You can add the groups or users to target audience , who have access to library. This will avoid users to see access denied and only user who have access can see the webpart and content in it.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, Why does it work on a non-webpart page? is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Which SharePoint Verison are you using ? Does access denied is for the page or on the zone where web part is added ?

Comment: 2010 enterprise, it happens on the zone section where the webpart has been added.